# Request failed with status code 500 React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, https, axios

i have React Native application that request data to backend server, as I deployed the node js application on server and replace the IP address from local computer IP address to provided server IP address and when I make request it just says in console `Request failed with status code 500` and if I change the IP address of local computer same backend application it works as expected.

```
 var baseIp = "http://182.180.106.200:3000/";

 axios.post(`${baseIp}/signin`, params, {
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
            })
            .then(async function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                let token = response.data.token;
                let userName = response.data.name;
                let email = response.data.email;
                let address = response.data.address;

                await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("username", userName);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("email", email);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("address", address);

                Actions.main_menu();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Server Side Error");
            });
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the redbox you see on your react-native app? It would hopefully provide more details on the error

Comment: i don't see any kind of red box or error just a message in browser console says Request failed with status code 500 React Native

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is as follows.

1. A problem caused by a temporary service outage or an abnormality in
   the server due to heavy server usage.
2. Error in server script.

So it's hard to say it's a code problem, but I think the address is wrong.

You can change this

```js
var baseIp = "http://182.180.106.200:3000";
...
`${baseIp}/signin`
```